# How to make the c string lexer example work?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

The following f/lex code is from its manual. But it won't run on their own. Some extra code is need to make it run. But I don't know how to add the extra code needed. Could anybody show me? Thanks.

```
%x str
%%
            char string_buf[MAX_STR_CONST];
            char *string_buf_ptr;

\"      string_buf_ptr = string_buf; BEGIN(str);

<str>\" { /* saw closing quote - all done */
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
        *string_buf_ptr = '\0';
        /* return string constant token type and
        * value to parser
        */
}

<str>\n {
/* error - unterminated string constant */
/* generate error message */
}

<str>\\[0-7]{1,3} {
        /* octal escape sequence */
        int result;
        (void) sscanf( yytext + 1, "%o", &result );
        if ( result > 0xff )
        /* error, constant is out-of-bounds */
        *string_buf_ptr++ = result;
}

<str>\\[0-9]+ {
        /* generate error - bad escape sequence; something
        * like '\48' or '\0777777'
        */
}
<str>\\n *string_buf_ptr++ = '\n';
<str>\\t *string_buf_ptr++ = '\t';
<str>\\r *string_buf_ptr++ = '\r';
<str>\\b *string_buf_ptr++ = '\b';
<str>\\f *string_buf_ptr++ = '\f';

<str>\\(.|\n) *string_buf_ptr++ = yytext[1];

<str>[^\\\n\"]+ {
    char *yptr = yytext;
    while ( *yptr ) *string_buf_ptr++ = *yptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing from that code snippet:

- How error conditions are handled.
- What token type is returned to the parser, and how the semantic type is represented.
- Tests to see if the fixed-length internal buffer is full.

The third one will require a test after every assignment through `string_buffer_ptr`, which could result in an errir condition, so it also goes back to the first point above.

Basically, these are things which totally depend on your application. How do you handle other kinds of errors? Do you attempt to recover and continue the parse or do you just write an error message and give up? You'll need to fill the handling of these errors consistently with other error handling.

The most likely code for communicating the result would be something like:

```
   BEGIN(INITIAL);
    *string_buf_ptr = '\0';
    /* return string constant token type and
     * value to parser
     */
    yylval.str = strdup(string_buf);
    return STRING_LITERAL;
```

But of course you'll need to replace `str` with the correct tag for a `char*` in your semantic union (assuming you are using one) and replace the `return` value with the correct token name. And you might prefer to use `malloc` and `strcpy` instead of `strdup`, although there's a lot to be saud for just making sure you have a backup definition of `strdup` in case you need one.

Comment: Could you make the simplest assumption to make the code working?

Comment: The simplest assumption is that you don't need anything returned and that you don't care about error messages, in which case the code will work as is :-) But it won't be very useful. Otherwise, I cannot see anyway for you to avoid specifying the things which I indicated, which you would do by writing a few lines of code.